Email, PWA and Thunderbird
I ordered a ThinkPad X1 Carbon with Ubuntu pre-installed. It should arrive next week. Very excited to switch from macOS. I have a question about email. Can I create an Outlook PWA with Firefox? Alternatively, how does Thunderbird handle Outlook.com email? Outlook always ran nicely with Apple Mail. Hoping my switch to Linux won't cause any undue problems with email.

Outlook PWA doesn't work in Firefox, that's an Edge feature.  Thunderbird works fine with Outlook.com addresses though as it's OAuth capable.
